# MySQL DATE_ADD with DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a premium date column of the DATETIME type in my MySQL database. If the column value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00, the query does not update the data.

```sql
UPDATE users SET premium_date = DATE_ADD(premium_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY) WHERE id=? LIMIT 1;
```

If there is already a date, it extends it.

How can I make it update?

Comment: What is `'..days..'`?  It doesn't look like a valid SQL statement.

Comment: It's a day from textbox, e.g 10 days

Comment: *If the column value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00* .. this means that the value is invalid. Invalid data plus any data produces invalid result.

Comment: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value is for new records

Comment: *0000-00-00 00:00:00 value is for new records* MySQL treates this as incorrect value: *"Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), if the SQL mode permits this conversion."*, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90022234159d19c07d653466d4f2b760

Comment: Well... what do you want to obtain after adding 10 days to this zero date?

Comment: I think i should use NOW() + INTERVAL 10 day

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not a valid SQL statement. For example, if the interval is 10 days, the query should look like this:

```
UPDATE users SET premium_date = DATE_ADD(premium_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
WHERE id=? 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes and it looks like this

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using NOW() + INTERVAL 10 days. Because I was trying to add 10 days to 0000 value.